# question about rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

consider this code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :posts, :through => :views, :uniq => true

  has_many :favorites
  has_many :posts, :through => :favorites, :uniq => true

  has_many :votes
  has_many :posts, :through => :votes, :uniq => true
end

# controller code

user = User.find(3)
posts = user.posts # ??
```

that said i have established three relationships between posts and users, through *different* way.  But what about the last line??? how can I tell rails that I want to get the posts through views or favorites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give each association a different name, but point it at the same model using the :class_name option. Like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :views
  has_many :view_posts, :through => :views, :class_name => 'Post', :uniq => true, 

  has_many :favorites
  has_many :favorite_posts, :through => :favorites, :class_name => 'Post', :uniq => true

  has_many :votes
  has_many :vote_posts, :through => :votes, :class_name => 'Post', :uniq => true
end

# Then...
User.find(3).favorite_posts
```

You may also find [named_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#M002177) useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the associations different names.  The 2nd and 3rd `has_many :posts` just overwrite the previous ones.  You will need something like `has_many :view_posts`, `has_many :favorite_posts`, etc.